# Pycharm not saving settings

Tags: settings, pycharm

I don't know if this is a question for SO, but I have seen others on here. I recently installed Pycharm 2.7.3 on my Mac, OSX 10.8.4. I want it to autocomplete, and make suggestions(Intentions), I thought it would happen automatically, apparently not. So I went into Preferences | Python Debugger and checked of "collect run-time types information for code insight" I it apply I hit ok and went on with my programing. I've done that 3 times now. Likewise when I tried to alter some Keymaps, they worked for that session but once I closed Pycharm they were gone. Similarly with my projects, nothing in the projects tab, or file I have open carries over after closing Pycharm. Can anyone tell me what's wrong?

Comment: It sounds like maybe you have a file permissions problem. Find where PyCharm is installed and make sure your user has read/write permission on the settings files.

Comment: permit me to sound befuddled for a moment, but how exactly do I do that? Does that intail going into PyCharm.app and doing something like chmod 777 on everything in there?

Comment: yep exactly. That's all I can think, it doesn't feel like a PyCharm specific issue.

Comment: Maybe your file .idea/workspace.xml is corrupt in some way - it was the case in my project. Try making a backup of the file, and then delete .idea/workspace.xml. It will be recreated when restarting PyCharm.